# Javascript from JSON if parameter is true

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am using the TMDB API to get the details of movies and I need to grab the trailer from Youtube. If my JSON results are like this...

```
{
  id: 568124,
  results: [
    {
      iso_639_1: "en",
      iso_3166_1: "US",
      name: "What Else Can I Do?",
      key: "PnJY20UCH9c",
      site: "YouTube",
      size: 1080,
      type: "Clip",
      official: true,
      published_at: "2021-12-13T21:54:56.000Z",
      id: "61b7d50b037264001cadc6e1",
    },
    {
      iso_639_1: "en",
      iso_3166_1: "US",
      name: "Official Trailer",
      key: "CaimKeDcudo",
      site: "YouTube",
      size: 1080,
      type: "Trailer",
      official: true,
      published_at: "2021-09-29T13:00:05.000Z",
      id: "615570dd07e281008dac4a0e",
    },
  ],
};
```

How can I ONLY grab the KEY from the video marked with the NAME 'OFFICIAL TRAILER'.
Right now, I can get the first result ([0]) from the list with the below code...

```
let movieTrailerUrl = data.videos.results[0].key;
document.getElementById('movie-trailer').innerHTML +=
`<div class="video-responsive"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${movieTrailerUrl}" title="${movieTitle}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>`;
```

But I need to make sure the only video chosen from the JSON results is the one marked 'OFFICIAL TRAILER'. Is it possible to do something like 'get the key only if the 'name' is equal to 'Official Trailer'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.find` to find the matching node with its name. Here I have considered that you are trying to find an item from the array where the name is exactly `"Official Trailer"`. Use the name and title of that matcing node to create the video link

```js
const apiResponse = {
  id: 568124,
  results: [
    {
      iso_639_1: "en",
      iso_3166_1: "US",
      name: "What Else Can I Do?",
      key: "PnJY20UCH9c",
      site: "YouTube",
      size: 1080,
      type: "Clip",
      official: true,
      published_at: "2021-12-13T21:54:56.000Z",
      id: "61b7d50b037264001cadc6e1",
    },
    {
      iso_639_1: "en",
      iso_3166_1: "US",
      name: "Official Trailer",
      key: "CaimKeDcudo",
      site: "YouTube",
      size: 1080,
      type: "Trailer",
      official: true,
      published_at: "2021-09-29T13:00:05.000Z",
      id: "615570dd07e281008dac4a0e",
    },
  ],
};

const movieTrailer = apiResponse.results.find(node => node.name.toUpperCase() === 'OFFICIAL TRAILER')
const movieTrailerUrl = movieTrailer.key;
const movieTitle = movieTrailer.name; // Mark the correct node
document.getElementById('movie-trailer').innerHTML +=
  `<div class="video-responsive"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${movieTrailerUrl}" title="${movieTitle}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>`;
```

```html
<div id="movie-trailer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you need only one key which matched the name official trailer

```js
// this is your data i just added in the variable but you don't need to do this
const data = {
  id: 568124,
  results: [
    {
      iso_639_1: "en",
      iso_3166_1: "US",
      name: "What Else Can I Do?",
      key: "PnJY20UCH9c",
      site: "YouTube",
      size: 1080,
      type: "Clip",
      official: true,
      published_at: "2021-12-13T21:54:56.000Z",
      id: "61b7d50b037264001cadc6e1",
    },
    {
      iso_639_1: "en",
      iso_3166_1: "US",
      name: "Official Trailer",
      key: "CaimKeDcudo",
      site: "YouTube",
      size: 1080,
      type: "Trailer",
      official: true,
      published_at: "2021-09-29T13:00:05.000Z",
      id: "615570dd07e281008dac4a0e",
    },
  ],
};

const {results } = data
console.log(results)

let key
results.forEach((e) => {
    if(e.name.includes("Official Trailer")) {
    key = e.key
  }
})
console.log(key)
```

Comment: This might work faster if you use a for instead of forEach and put a break if you found the needed key.

Comment: You nice comment brother... yeah let me edit it then

Comment: That works in terms of getting it to print in console.log, but how does it translate to this line? let movieTrailerUrl = data.videos.results[0].key;

Comment: You can use find borther for that it will return that element to you the new answer is being posted you can check that too

Answer (score 1):

```
const movieTrailer = data.videos.results.find((trailer) => trailer.name === 'Official Trailer');

// if statment needed because `.find` can return undefined in case it doesn't find the value
if (movieTrailer) {
    console.log(movieTrailer.key);
}
```

You would probably also want to lowercase values, eg. `trailer.name.toLowerCase() === 'Official Trailer'.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
let movieTrailerUrl = data.videos.results.find((result) => result.key === 'What you want')
```

The `find` method in Array is return the first element what be evaluated `true` in array .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you want to get the "official trailer" object from an array of objects

```js
var obj = {
  id: 568124,
  results: [
    {
      iso_639_1: "en",
      iso_3166_1: "US",
      name: "What Else Can I Do?",
      key: "PnJY20UCH9c",
      site: "YouTube",
      size: 1080,
      type: "Clip",
      official: true,
      published_at: "2021-12-13T21:54:56.000Z",
      id: "61b7d50b037264001cadc6e1",
    },
    {
      iso_639_1: "en",
      iso_3166_1: "US",
      name: "Official Trailer",
      key: "CaimKeDcudo",
      site: "YouTube",
      size: 1080,
      type: "Trailer",
      official: true,
      published_at: "2021-09-29T13:00:05.000Z",
      id: "615570dd07e281008dac4a0e",
    },
  ],
};

console.log(obj.results.find(element => element.name === "Official Trailer"))
console.log(obj.results.find(element => element.name === "Official Trailer").key)
```